# How would you write an Sheet which does only make a Solid Line on top of the Template-cell and the left side?

Tags: css, border

I have a Template constructed out of many Cells as part of a Form. I wrote several Types which have borders background colours and so on, so that i , in the end, could apply them to the cells at the edges and construct a box around the whole Information by putting them together. To make it clear here an example of what i try to do:

if you had 9 cells in form a cupe the middle top one would just have a border on the top the top left one would have borders on the left and the top and so on. That works well for the "straight" parts, in this example the middle parts of every side.

But the corners just don't appear neither the background color or the borders.

What i tried is basically that . I wrote the following code for the bottom right corner:

```css
.brechtsunten {
  background-color: #81a0e9 !important;
  border-right: 2px solid !important;
  border-bottom: 2px solid !important;
  border-color: #183b8b !important;
}
```

And it does nothing , and by nothing i mean it doesn't even appear in the style filter of the inspector section if i open the form extern in my browser, so i get nothing i could work with like a syntax error message.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please take a [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) of the [help centre](http://stackoverflow.com/help) to see [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).  We cannot help you if you do not provide enough code to replicate your issue - see how to create a [MCVE]

Answer (score 0):

You have to specify the border property if you use `border-bottom`

Example

`border-bottom-width: 33px;`

The correct way to write your CSS

```
  background-color: #81a0e9 !important;
  border-right-width: 2px;
  border-bottom-width: 2px;
  border: 0px solid #183b8b;
}
```